# Store a struct with vectors in shared memory inc C

Tags: c, matrix, shared-memory

I'm trying to store a 2D Array (matrix) in shared memory. I'm using ubuntu and C.

This is my code:

The struct

```
typedef struct {
    int data[COLUN_CAP];
} Colonna;

typedef struct {
    int nc;
    key_t colK;
    Colonna colonne[10];
} Matrix;
```

The function that initiates the matrix:

```
void iniz_mat(Matrix *M, int n) {
    M->nc = n;
    int i, k;
    for (i = 0; i < M->nc; i++) {      
        printf("Colonna: %d \n", i);
        for (k = 0; k < COLUN_CAP; k++) {  
            M->colonne[i].data[k] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Main program

```
key_t shmKM;   
int n;

shmKM = ftok(PATH_SHM, CHAR_SHMM);
scanf("%d", &n);
int idshmM = shmget(shmKM, sizeof(Matrix) + sizeof(Colonna) * 10, IPC_CREAT | 0664);
Matrix *Mat;
Mat = (Matrix *)shmat(idshmM, 0, 0);
iniz_mat(Mat, n);
```

I get segmentation fault (core dumped) error. I was looking to store a matrix with a variable amount of columns, but apparently I can't store a fixed one. Tips?

---

edit:
So, for the variable amount of columns I tried:

```
typedef struct {
    int nc;
    key_t colK;
    Colonna colonne[];
} Matrix;
```

and of course:

```
int idshmM = shmget(shmKM, sizeof(Matrix) + sizeof(Colonna) * n, IPC_CREAT | 0664);
```

it doesn't give any error, but when I print the matrix I only get the first 2 rows of each colum.

The code for the print function is the following:

```
void print_matrix(Matrix *M) {
    int i, k;
    for (k = 0; k < COLUN_CAP; k++) {
        for (i = 0; i < M->nc; i++)
            printf("%d  ", M->colonne[k].data[i]); 
        printf("\n");      
    }
}
```

So I get the visual representation of the matrix. `COLUN_CAP` is the number of elements of each column and is set to `5`.

---

Oh the print function is wrong (inverted i and k) I feel so stupid. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code. And nothing that can be used as one with appropriate semantics.

Comment: How could I store this struct in shared memory?

Comment: Suggest you start by adding in error checking code to verify the return value of all functions. If that doesn't show the error then use a debugger. And finally if you still can't work it out please post a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample code, why do you allocate room for 10 `Colonna` structures?  `Matrix` has room for up to 10 Colonna, handling more than `10` would require a flexible array.  Using a flexible array, you can allocate room for the appropriate number of `Colonna` structures and address them in a portable fashion.  Use this:

```
typedef struct {
    int data[COLUN_CAP];
} Colonna;

typedef struct {
    int nc;
    key_t colK;
    Colonna colonne[];
} Matrix;

int idshmM = shmget(shmKM, sizeof(Matrix) + sizeof(Colonna) * n, IPC_CREAT | 0664);
```

Futhermore, you should check for errors in the `shmget` and `shmat` system calls.  `shmat` returns `(void *)-1` upon error.  Use `strerror()` to output a informative error messages.

Comment: edit: It actually worked after rebooting the VM. Now I would like to pass a variable number of colums. I edit the main post so I can write the code I tried.

Comment: @alteration: *I only get the first 2 rows of each column*... what is the value of `COLUN_CAP`?  Also post the code for the printing function

Comment: The segmentation fault error I think was becouse I didn't free the memory at the end of the program, so after several runs I had to reboot. The problem I got in the first place was the one I described in the edit of the main post.

Comment: @alteration: Add error checking in your code, the errors will no longer crash your program and you will get useful diagnostic messages.